# Error installing Rstudio on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, rstudio

When I try installing Rstudio Desktop, I get this error when I run `yay -Syyu rstudio-desktop` in terminal.

```
In file included from /home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/ExponentialBackoff.hpp:24,
from /home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/ExponentialBackoff.cpp:18:
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp:362:9: error: ‘set’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
362 |    std::set<T, std::less<T>, std::allocator<T> > set_;
|         ^~~
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp:28:1: note: ‘std::set’ is defined in header ‘<set>’; did you forget to ‘#include <set>’?
27 | #include <core/Log.hpp>
+++ |+#include <set>
28 |
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp: In member function ‘bool rstudio::core::thread::ThreadsafeSet<T>::contains(const T&) const’:
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp:322:17: error: ‘set_’ was not declared in this scope
322 |          return set_.find(value) != set_.end();
|                 ^~~~
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp: In member function ‘void rstudio::core::thread::ThreadsafeSet<T>::insert(const T&)’:
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp:334:10: error: ‘set_’ was not declared in this scope
334 |          set_.insert(value);
|          ^~~~
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp: In member function ‘void rstudio::core::thread::ThreadsafeSet<T>::insert(T&&)’:
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp:343:10: error: ‘set_’ was not declared in this scope
343 |          set_.insert(value);
|          ^~~~
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp: In member function ‘void rstudio::core::thread::ThreadsafeSet<T>::remove(const T&)’:
/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-2022.12.0-353/src/cpp/core/include/core/Thread.hpp:352:21: error: ‘set_’ was not declared in this scope
352 |          auto itr = set_.find(value);
|                     ^~~~
make[2]: *** [src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/build.make:202: src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/ExponentialBackoff.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:521: src/cpp/core/CMakeFiles/rstudio-core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/myusername/.cache/yay/rstudio-desktop/src/build'
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
Aborting...
-> error making: rstudio-desktop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error with yay, but the RStudio build seems to be broken for some compilers (invoked by make, which is invoked by pkgbuild, which is invoked by yay).

Either install the [binary version](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rstudio-desktop-bin) of RStudio, or wait for the rstudio AUR to be updated to the [patched version](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12611).